# QAbstractListModel & QML: refresh row color

Tags: c++, qt, model, tableview, qml

I have a [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) and I emit [dataChanged(…)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) when my data change, my view content is correctly updated.

But only content, not color: if the color depends on the state of my model item, then it is not refreshed.

Here is a simplification of my `itemDelegate` in my `TableView` in QML:

```
TableView {
    model: myModel

    itemDelegate: Text {
        text: debug("value", styleData.value)
        color: debug("color", myModel.getMyBooleanState(styleData.row) ? 'blue' : 'red')
    }

    // …
}
```

`debug()` just logs when the function is called:

```
function debug(tag, value) {
    console.log(tag + ": " + value)
    return value
}
```

`getMyBooleanState()` is a member function of my model:

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool getMyBooleanState(int rowIndex) const;
```

On start, both text and color are correctly initialized. But every time I emit `dataChanged()`, only the value is updated, not the color.

How can I update the color?

Comment: Can't you define a role for such a purpose? The function is evaluated only the first time (given the correct, initial, behaviour). You need a `PROPERTY` there or better a boolean role.

Comment: Suppose you use a role for that purpose. How would you do?

Comment: Something like `color: myCheckRole ? "lightred" : "steelblue"`

Comment: I don't have access to `myCheckRole` from here: `ReferenceError: myCheckRole is not defined`.

Comment: Ops sorry, didn't see the `TableView` in the code. Didn't played around with the component enough to help. My apoligizes.